# Polytopes: affine isomorphism implies combinatorial isomorphism

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-geometry, polytopes

Let $P \subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$ and $Q \subseteq \mathbb{R}^e$ be (convex) polytopes. Define them to be affinely isomorphic if there is an affine map $f \colon \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}^e$ whose restriction to $P$ gives a bijection $P \to Q$. I want to show that if $P$ and $Q$ are affinely isomorphic then their face lattices are isomorphic.

Any help? I was able to show that $f$ induces a bijection between the vertices of the polytopes but then I got stuck. I also tried to show this directly from the definitions but that seems really difficult. A face of $P$ is of the form $F = P \cap H$ where $H = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^d \mid cx = c_0\}$ where $c$ is some row vector and $c_0 \in \mathbb{R}$, and where $cx \le c_0$ for all $x \in P$. If I take the image of $F$ under $f$ then it is not clear to me that the image is a face of $Q$ since I can't seem to find a suitable linear equation on the codomain side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit. I finally found a way to prove this that I feel satisfied with. A lemma that needs to be proved before this proof is that if $f \colon P \to Q$ is a bijection that extends to an affine map $\mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}^e$, then $f^{-1} \colon Q \to P$ also extends to an affine map $\mathbb{R}^e \to \mathbb{R}^d$. Proving this lemma is no trivial task though, but I'll skip it.

Suppose $P \subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$ and $Q \subseteq \mathbb{R}^e$ be polytopes, an suppose $f \colon P \to Q$ is a bijection that extends to an affine map $\mathbb{R}^e \to \mathbb{R}^d$.
Let $f(x) = L(x) + b$ for some linear $L \colon \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}^e$ and vector $b \in \mathbb{R}^e$.
Now $f^{-1} \colon Q \to P$ extends to an affine map $g \colon \mathbb{R}^e \to \mathbb{R}^d$. Let $g(x) = T(x) + a$ where $T \colon \mathbb{R}^e \to \mathbb{R}^d$ is linear and $a \in \mathbb{R}^d$.
Now
\begin{equation*}
    g(f(x)) = T(L(x) + b) + a = x
\end{equation*}
for all $x \in P$.
Let $F$ be a face of $P$.
Now
\begin{equation*}
    F = P \cap \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^d \mid \alpha(x) = c \}
\end{equation*}
where $\alpha \in (\mathbb{R}^d)^*$ and $c \in \mathbb{R}$ and where $\alpha(x) \le c$ for all $x \in P$.
We claim that $f(F)$ is a face of $Q$ given by
\begin{equation*}
    f(F) = Q \cap \{ y \in \mathbb{R}^e \mid \alpha(T(y)) = c - \alpha(a) \}. \tag{1}
\end{equation*}
First we check that the inequality $\alpha(T(y)) \le c - \alpha(a)$ is valid for $Q$.
Let $y \in Q$.
Now $y = L(x) + b$ for some $x \in P$.
Thus
\begin{align*}
    \alpha(T(y)) = \alpha(T(L(x) + b)) = \alpha(x - a) = \alpha(x) - \alpha(a) \le c - \alpha(a).
\end{align*}
Next we show that we have equality in (1).
Let $f(x) \in f(F)$ where $x \in F$.
Now $f(x) \in Q$ and
\begin{equation*}
    \alpha(T(f(x))) = \alpha(T(L(x) + b)) = \alpha(x-a) = \alpha(x) - \alpha(a) = c - \alpha(a).
\end{equation*}
Then let $y \in Q$ be such that $\alpha(T(y)) = c - \alpha(a)$.
Now $y = f(x)$ for some $x \in P$.
We claim that $x \in F$.
For this we note that
\begin{equation*}
    c - \alpha(a) = \alpha(T(y)) = \alpha(T(f(x))) = \alpha(x) - \alpha(a)
\end{equation*}
and thus $\alpha(x) = c$.
So $x \in F$.
We therefore have the equality in (1).
We have now seen that $f$ maps faces of $P$ to faces of $Q$.
By symmetry, $f^{-1}$ maps faces of $Q$ to faces of $P$.
Thus the map $F \mapsto f(F)$ is a bijection $L(P) \to L(Q)$.
Furthermore, it and its inverse are order preserving since
\begin{equation*}
    F \subseteq G \iff f(F) \subseteq f(G)
\end{equation*}
for all faces $F,G \in L(P)$.
Hence $L(P) \cong L(Q)$.